# Where-Condition as IN(Subquery) with Doctrine2 in Symfony2.3.1 doesnt work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, where-clause, subquery

---- Done with Symfony2.3.1 and Doctrine2 ----

Sorry, i hope i was not too stupid to find a suitable solution for my problem. I try to build a Query for hours.

```
SELECT * FROM product
    WHERE product_id in
    (
       SELECT product_id from (
          SELECT count(*) as result_amount, product_id FROM product_x_attribut
          JOIN productattribut on productattribut_id = productattribut.id
          WHERE (
            productkey = "price" and
            stringType = "premium"
          ) or (
            productkey = "size" and 
            stringType = "S"
          )
          GROUP BY product_id
          HAVING result_amount = 2
       ) as temp
    )
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY p0_.name ASC
```

This is the SQL which works fine in phpmyAdmin.

This can be seen like

```
Select * from abc where abc.x in ( Select * from ( select * from ) as abcd )
```

So there is one core query, i call it subSubQuery, the second query around the core will be called subQuery and the outer Query is just the outer Query, no a Subquery.
I could build the subSubQuery with Doctrine2.

But i cannot built the subQuery like this

```
Select product_id from ( $subSubQuery->getQuery()->getDQL() )
```

I want to do the subQuery like this

```
$subQuery = $repositoryProduct->createQueryBuilder('product');
$subQuery->add('select', 'product_id');
$subQuery->add('from',$subSubQuery->getDQL() );
// However to set an alias is a miracle for me, this didnt work off course
$subQuery->add('as','tmp' );
```

This is the subQuery.
I also cannot build the outer Query

```
Select * from abc where abc.x in ( $subQuery->getQuery()->getDQL() )
```

I want to do this like this

```
$query->where(
  $query->expr()->in('product.id', $subQuery->getDQL() )
);
```

But i try to build this with Doctrine2 like this:

I am so down, i tried ->getSQL(), ->getDQL(), i tried as much as i was able to detect as a suitable tiny step to a solution for this problem and i has tried as much keyword in google as my finger were able to write... I hope someone could help me to find a solution...

Thanks a lot to each helpful advise.

Answer (score 0):

I know that statements like this work:

```
$qbGames->andWhere($qbGames->expr()->in('game.id',$qbGameId->getDQL()));
```

Your question is kind of hard to follow.  Consider using pastebin to show all your mappings as they currently exist.  And then maybe presenting a simplieid query?

My $qbGameId query was built with:

```
   $qbGameId = $em->createQueryBuilder();

   $qbGameId->addSelect('distinct gameGameId.id');

   $qbGameId->from('ZaysoCoreBundle:Event','gameGameId');

   // Assorted joins and where conditions
```

Comment: I did it like that, but i get an Error "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 20 near 'SELECT count(productxattribut.id),': Error: Class 'SELECT' is not defined. " because the $subQuery->getDQL() returns "SELECT count(p0_.id) AS sclr0, p1_.id AS id1 FROM produkt_x_attribut p0_ INNER JOIN produktattribut p2_ ON p0_.produktattribut_id = p2_.id INNER JOIN produkt p1_ ON p0_.produkt_id = p1_.id WHERE (p2_.schluessel = ? AND p0_.stringType = ?) OR (p2_.schluessel = ? AND p0_.stringType = ?) GROUP BY p0_.produkt_id HAVING count(p0_.id) = ? "

Comment: Yep.  Problem is that I have no idea as to what query your actually tried.  Just too much in your question.  Try updating your question and say something like:  I tried this exact query and I got this error message.  I updated my answer, it's possible you are not using distinct in your sub query?